# unified diff: text after second @@ of a hunk

Tags: diff

I could not find a specification for the unified diff format on the web. Often one sees text from the diffed files after the second `@@` of a hunk, like this:

```
@@ -209,4 +196,4 @@ cleanup:
    _TEMPLATE(T, vec) (X);
 }

-#endif
\ No newline at end of file
+#endif
```

Does the text after the second `@@` matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stumped me too as it was breaking the open-source patch parser I was using. It seems this isn't well understood even by tool makers.

Apparently the text after the `@@` is generated by the `--show-c-function` flag to diff, documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/C-Function-Headings.html). In your case the title is a bit of misnomer, since your text is not a function definition, but (probably) a label which gets caught when diff looks above the edited lines for the most identifier which isn't indented.

You can see an example of how this feature works here:

**Normal**

```
diff --unified=3 <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/97574c57cf26ace9b8609575bbab66465924fef7/gcc/config/sparc/sparc.c) <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/17fc6eeba9352b97ba16d64fd1de9a5bdc081062/gcc/config/sparc/sparc.c) | sed -n '3p'
```

output: `@@ -648,7 +648,6 @@`

**--show-c-function**

```
diff --show-c-function --unified=3 <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/97574c57cf26ace9b8609575bbab66465924fef7/gcc/config/sparc/sparc.c) <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/17fc6eeba9352b97ba16d64fd1de9a5bdc081062/gcc/config/sparc/sparc.c) | sed -n '3p'
```

output: `@@ -648,7 +648,6 @@ static reg_class_t sparc_secondary_reloa`

As far as I can tell, the text after `@@` is mostly for human consumption and you can safely ignore it if you want to.